# Sending form data from react to express using action method

Tags: reactjs, express

This is my Login component and I am trying to send the form data using the action method rather than fetch

```
import {useState} from "react";

const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  return (
    <>
      <form
        className="login"
        action="http://localhost:3000/login"
        method="POST"
      >
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
        <input
          id="username"
          type="text"
          placeholder="username"
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          value={username}
        />
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="password"
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          id="password"
          value={password}
        />
        <button>Login</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

And this is my app.js file where I am handling the post request

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(req.body);
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Listenting on port 3000");
});
```

As you can see I am trying to send the req.body as a response but all I am getting in the terminal is {}.

Can you tell me where the error is?

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be right to me but still three thing you can do
`add the from-control class` to the form

`add the type submit to the button`

`lastly try to do the url_encoded: false`
here the url options

[url options](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions)

from the original docs